# Data flow for laravel app for mobile

Tags: laravel, mobile

Im building a mobile app (word game) where only user that are athenticate can play.
The main screen will contain buttons to

```
1 - login by having an account created on our app 
2 - create an account on our app
3 - login by authenticating yourself via facebook
```

How should the laravel app look like? Should I have some filter so laravel app detect if a user logged in? And if its not the case then redirect to AuthController?
Also, what is best practice for authentication in mobile laravel app? I mean: when a user logs in, should he be identified by session or by some token?

Comment: Are you building a native app or just a responsive website? If you are building a native app you will simply create a REST api.